# Disable whole body except a div

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I'm working with react and I'm doing a pop-up menu, but I want to disable the whole body so the user can't click anything else on it, except my pop-up menu and I don't know how

Answer (score 1):

A solution commonly used in this case is :
A shadow with an high `z-index` (9999): `<div class="shadow"><div>`
Inside this div your `<menu><a href="#link1">Link 1<a><menu>`

A background with opacity is better for your shadow, but if you want a tranparent background, explicitly specify this to override the normal click behavior :

```
.shadow {
 background: transparent;
 display: block;
 z-index: 9999;
 position: fixed;
 left: 0;
 top: 0;
 height: 100%;
 width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Great news ^^ :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a state that changes the "display" property of elements to either block or none. By using the below state, only one of your elements will be visible at a time.

```
const [viewState,setviewState]=useState(false);

<div class="mainContent" style={{display:viewState?'none':'block'}}> {content} </div> 
<div class="popUp" style={{display:!viewState?'none':'block'}}> </div>
```

So now whenever you toggle the viewState, the display property will also be toggled, which will disable your whole mainContent element and enable popup and vice versa. To toggle just use the following.

```
setviewState(!viewState)
```